# How to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging in React Native expo managed workflow for receiving notifications?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo, react-native-firebase

I tried to implement it using @react-native-firebase/app but it is asking me to convert from expo managed workflow to expo bare workflow. Is there any way to receive notifications directly from Firebase cloud messaging to expo app using expo managed workflow?

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/?